# "StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED" error while using bigtable.scan() function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a millions of articles in bigtable and to scan 50,000 articles I have used something as :

```
for key, data in mytable.scan(limit=50000):
         print (key,data)
```

It works fine for limit upto `10000` but as I exceed the limit of `10000` I get this error

> _Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED)

Comment: Are you using [Python Client Libraries](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/usage.html) for Bigtable?

Comment: @Yurci Yes!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There was a fix for this problem, where the client automatically retries temporary failures like this one.  That fix was not released yet, but will hopefully be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I had to retrieve data from many rows at the same time. What you're using looks like the hbase client, my solution is using the native one, so I'll try to post both - one which I tested and one which might work.

I never found an example which would demonstrate how to simply iterate over the rows as they come using the `consume_next()` method, which is mentioned [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/data-api.html#stream-many-rows-from-a-table) and I didn't manage to figure it out on my own. Calling `consume_all()` for too many rows yielded the same `DEADLINE EXCEEDED` error.

```
LIMIT = 10000
previous_start_key = None
while start_key != previous_start_key:
    previous_start_key = start_key
    row_iterator = bt_table.read_rows(start_key=start_key, end_key=end_key, 
        filter_=filter_, limit=LIMIT)
    row_iterator.consume_all()
    for _row_key, row in row_iterator.rows.items():
        row_key = _row_key.decode()
        if row_key == previous_start_key:  # Avoid repeated processing
            continue
        # do stuff 
        print(row)  
        start_key = row_key
```

So basically you can start with whatever start_key, retrieve 10k results, do `consume_all()`, then retrieve the next batch starting where you left off, and so on, until some reasonable condition applies.

For you it might be something like:

```
row_start = None
for i in range(5):
    for key, data in mytable.scan(row_start=row_start, limit=10000):
        if key == row_start:  # Avoid repeated processing
            continue
        print (key,data)
        row_start = key
```

There might be a much better solution, and I really want to know what it is, but this works for me for the time being.

Comment: So, in second one you have put the limit of 10000. How it iterate when it comes to 10001th article? What would be the next limit of process articles after 10000 articles get processed?

Comment: You can think of it as a batch size. It processes 10,000 articles after the `row_start`. So in the beginning, you start with None, which would be the first row. In second iteration, your start key will be the last key of previous iteration, and it will return the second 10k items, rows 10,000-20,000, and so on. Actually, this points out a mistake, those rows (10,000th one, 20,000th etc.) would get processed twice. Let me fix that.

Comment: In first code it gives error as `NameError: name 'start_key' is not defined`

Comment: Of course it's not, it's a snippet and those variables are application specific, right? Just like `end_key`, `filter_` and whatever you do with the `row`.

Comment: so do I need to give any value for `start_key`? `while start_key != previous_start_key:` for this it gives an error

Comment: I mean, you will have to do some changes to the code yourself, you do understand that, right? You can use an empty string. Docs: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/table.html#google.cloud.bigtable.table.Table.read_rows